# React Native animations

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native

We need to decide what platform to choose for our iOS & Android applications - React Native or completely native applications (Swift/Java).

Generally, React Native is much better for us because we already have React.JS apps. The main concern about React Native is that we need difficult animations.

Is it possible to implement with React Native animations of this kind?

- [Dribble #1](https://dribbble.com/shots/1945593-Login-Home-Screen)
- [Dribble #2](https://dribbble.com/shots/2548398-Wallet-Concept-Sketch-Principle-Freebie)
- [Dribble #3](https://dribbble.com/shots/2006165-Mobile-Wallet-App-Animation)
- [Dribble #4](https://dribbble.com/shots/2930593-Wallet-interaction)

If yes - does it works on low-end Android phones?

Answer (score 2):

AirBnB introduced [Lottie](http://airbnb.io/lottie/) a while back with this very purpose.
As for the low-end, it seems to support ICS and up, so... maybe.

Comment: As a shameless self-promotion, I wrote an article about Lottie for React Native. It contains the basics of implementing it: https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/boost-your-user-experience-with-lottie-for-react-native-5da1ac589982

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to implement something similar to Dribbble #2, #3, #4 with React Native [Animations](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html). But for screen transitions in Dribble #1 and good performance on old devices, I would recommend checking a different technology - [Flutter](https://flutter.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two great youtube channels dedicated to react-native animations. They will help you express the logic and patterns to do what you want.

**1)** https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTcH04SRuyedaSuuQVeAcdg

**2)** https://www.youtube.com/user/wcandill